# Is it possible to access windows application functions when ever enters url on web browser on google chrome and returns value to web browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I'm trying to create a windows form application, I have some dll file which supports only in windows form application or console application projects(not in web application). Here I want to return data/values to web browser whenever someone enters url(like 192.168.1.14/getfulldata). I am completely confused about this

Comment: What prevents you referencing and using your dll in your web application directly? What makes it 'not supported' in web application.

Comment: Its works in webapplication also sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

> I want to return data/values to web browser whenever someone enters
>   url(like 192.168.1.14/getfulldata)

Yes, expose that particular functionality as REST service using Web Api (an GET operation). Read more about it on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio.